# Positional parameter cannot be found

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure why I'm getting the following error

`Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Code\PS\Auths\2.jpg'.
At C:\Code\PS\auth-grab.ps1:9 char:12`

**C:\Code\PS\Auths\2.jpg is the correct path.**

(I'm getting one of these for each of the items in the pipeline)

When I echo $rv I get the correct pathand $_ should be right. Where am I going wrong?

oops script below :

```
function Generate-FileName($fi)
{           
    $rv = "C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name
    #echo rv    
}

Get-ChildItem Auths\*.* -include 1.jpg, 2.jpg | 
ForEach-Object {        
    Copy-Item $_ -destination Generate-FileName(Get-ChildItem $_)       
}
```

Note if i echo $rv I get the path I want

Comment: You should post the code from that `auth-grab.ps1` file

Comment: totally forgot to post the code *facepalm*

Comment: Isn't it some problem with spaces in file names or in your parameters?

Comment: There's no spaces in the filenames

Comment: Have you tried echoing out $_ ...whilst you're about it write-host $_.fullname and $_.name just to be sure you're working with the correct path?

Comment: Did you tried to add parameter name in front of $_ ? `Copy-Item -path $_ ...`

Comment: Didn't you forget to return `$rv` in your function?

Comment: Tried fullname, name and parameter name

Comment: I meant echo out what is in the source $_ variable... you seem confident the destination path is OK.  Copy-Item $_ <<this one.  Can you try Copy-Item $_.fullname

Comment: yeah sorry I've done that too. The error is actually stating that the $_ path is the problem, but it is the correct path.

Comment: Problem is the way you are calling Generate-FileName(...). See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the function - *Generate-FileName* in **brackets** like this -

```
ForEach-Object {        
    Copy-Item $_ -destination (Generate-FileName(Get-ChildItem $_))      
}
```

Enclosing it in parenthesis forces the [expression](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706).

**OR**

---

Copy the return value of the function in a variable and use the variable in the Copy-Item as below -

```
function Generate-FileName($fi)
{           
    "C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name
}

Get-ChildItem Auths\*.* -include 1.jpg, 2.jpg | 
ForEach-Object {   
    $destination =  Generate-FileName(Get-ChildItem $_)           
    Copy-Item $_ -destination $destination
}
```

Comment: You might not want to keep $rv at all. Just have this & try [I have not tried this part] - **"C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name**

Comment: the only reason I had $rv was to echo it.

Comment: yeah, I guess for debugging the value. But, in production script, you might not need it. Thats what I meant.

Comment: yeah removing $rv and not returning it works. e.g. function Generate-FileName($fi)
{   
 
 "C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name

}

Answer (score 0):

I think your function `Generate-FileName` doesn't return anything.

I think your script generate this line with copy-item:

```
Copy-Item C:\Code\PS\Auths\2.jpg -destination
```

Try it like this:

```
function Generate-FileName($fi)
{           
    $rv = "C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name
    return $rv # here is the change
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. It is the problem with function evaluation only. I tried the same sample in Powershell ISE.

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal I think that I found the right solution. You added `return`ing in your last edit and that was what I suggested (firstly in comments) and that was what solved the problem...

Comment: You may try what you are saying without modifying anything else except what you have suggested and run full code from John in ISE. Additionally, you may read John's comments too - _yeah removing $rv and not returning it works. e.g. function Generate-FileName($fi) {"C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name }_ Its not only returning. Its the way you call the function too. Moreover, $rv is not required. That was just for debugging purpose.

Comment: Ok. I get it. But I have a question: What is difference between `function Generate-FileName($fi) {"C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name }` and `function Generate-FileName($fi) {$rv = "C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name; return $rv } ` ?

Comment: We **don’t need** to use the return keyword like we do in C style function.  Whatever expressions and statements that have output will contribute to the output of our function. So, above we just want the output of _"C:\Code\PS\New\"+ $fi.Name_. For more in-depth understanding read here - http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/effective-powershell-item-7-understanding-output/ under the heading called - **Function Output Consists of Everything That Isn’t Captured**

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Then I don't get the comment _yeah removing $rv and not returning it works_ ...